# Magento .htaccess Redirect Loop

Tags: .htaccess, magento

I'm currently working on a Magento site where I'm trying to redirect all trafic that doesn't need to be on https to http as it is causing problems with a range of files that are included on this site (fonts, css & js).

I'd have thought that was fairly straight forward and have tried a range of suggestions I've found on Stack Overflow and elsewhere but with no luck.

Either the https pages just redirect to the home page, or I get a redirect loop.

My most recent attempt looked like this (which causes a redirect loop):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/onestepcheckout/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/customer/account/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

We do have a full page caching module installed. I'm not sure what affect might have but the issue occurs even when I turn that off.

Comment: Do you have any other rules?

Comment: Doesn't Magento manage the https and http itself on the links? Normally when you set "use secure blabla on frontend" it will only switch to https when the customer enters his account or on the checkout, the rest should stay http?

Comment: Jon Lin, there are other rule but I've put this one right at the top of the .htaccess rules. There's a few Redirect 301's in there, but otherwise it's just a standard Magento .htaccess. @Kenny Firefox has taken to using https connections if you have been to a page on that site that has a https page it's logged as a bug here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=769994